# Why does Protobuf generate outer classes for Java?

Tags: java, class, code-generation, protobuf

I googled this and found questions like "How to use Protobuf message as java class without a java outer class?" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312156/how-to-use-protobuf-message-as-java-class-without-a-java-outer-class) which talk about how one might tweak their Protobuf Java code generation. For example, that person wants to avoid having outer classes. The answer tells them about the "multiple files" option.

But I'd like to know why the Java generated code, by default, is split up this way. I didn't notice code split up like that when I used my same Protobuf files to generate Go code. I got just one struct per Protobuf message I defined. In Java, I get two classes per Protobuf message defined, and I can choose between them being nested or in separate files. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question really fits here - the "why" of how some tool does its job is often better asked on forums specific to those tools.

Comment: Noted. I posted in their Google Group instead, which appears to be how they want questions asked by the public: https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf/c/BpkWQXdKdyc

Comment: If you enable the multiple files option its not actually outer/inner classes. Also, from a technical standpoint, it seems to be necessary to have a class per protobuf source in order to manage extensions.

Comment: As stated in my question, I did find out about the option to enable to have it generate multiple files. But my question was more about why these two different ways to do it exist, not how to choose between one or the other. My post on the Google Group got a nice reply where they explained it's because of users asking for the multiple files option but them also wanting to not break existing stuff.